# Meta viewport - Device-width need to be a minimum

Tags: iphone, metadata, viewport, device-width

We have created a website that is optimized to 480px. But if we set the meta viewport to device-width with initial scale = 1 then on the iPhone the width is 320px and the site is to wide.

When setting the initial scale on 0.65 the site is good on the iPhone but than on the iPad the site is too small!

How can we put the minimal width of showing the site at 480px but without horizontal scrollbars? `Body { min-width 480px; }` is already set in the CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

If that doesn't work, you could work with media tags in CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
    body { -webkit-transform: scale(0.65); }
}
```

Comment: I solved the issue with the following code:

<meta name="viewport" content="width=480">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="480">